# MythTV + File Storage in one box

Tags: mythtv, mediaserver, file-server

I would like to build a headless Ubuntu server to work as (backup) file server + work as MythTV backend server recording and sharing TV in Home network.

It should have flexible hard drive handling to allow adding more disk (mostly old ones) to the pool and keep data safe if some disk will brake, like in UnRaid / FreeNas systems.

Is there something ready to use on top of Ubuntu servers to create something like this?

Thanks -El Toro

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do should be possible.  I suggest that you first get the headless backup file server running as you wish with out the Myth functions and then add the MythTV capability through Mythbuntu ( http://www.mythbuntu.org/existing-ubuntu ).